Как обойти блокировку?
Имеется у меня сайт на котором есть обычный поиск, при вводе туда название видео я отправляю запрос на другой сайт (не мой) и получаю там ссылку на видео, после эту ссылку я вставляю в тег video. Суть в том, что видео я на своем сайте не могу смотреть, оно попросту не загружается, а вот если через VPN смотреть, то все хорошо. Блокировка просмотра в некоторых странах заблокированная. Какие варианты есть для того, чтобы мои пользователи не включали VPN? У меня был вариант отправлять запрос на получение ссылки видео при помощи прокси, но потом так подумал, а смысл? Это ведь ничего не поменяется, т.к. ссылку я могу получить и без прокси.
